# Como acessar propiedades de um componente personalizado no react-native.ts?

Tags: typescript, react-native

No *react-native.js* você pode simplesmente acessar qualquer propiedade da seguinte forma:

```
const meuComponent = (props)=>{
    return(...);
}
```

Dentro do componente, dá pra acessar qualquer propiedade repasada a ele, desde que você coloque dentro do `tag`:

```
<MeuComponente algumaProp="qualquer coisa" />
```

Sendo assim, com `props.AlgumaProp` dá pra acessar o que foi passado pelo componente ou tela que a utilizou.

Gostaria de saber como fazer isso no *react-native.ts*, segue meu código:

```
interface ButtonsProps extends TouchableOpacityProps{
    title: string;
    enabled: boolean;
} 

...

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        backgroundColor: props.enabled? colors.green: colors.heading,
        height:56,
        borderRadius:16,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707327/passing-props-into-external-stylesheet-in-react-native

Veja esse tópico que contém algumas explicações mais detalhadas

```
interface ButtonsProps extends TouchableOpacityProps{
    title: string;
    enabled: boolean;
} 

const meuComponent = ({title, enabled}: ButtonsProps)=>{
    return(...);
}

export const styles = (iconColor,iconSize) => StyleSheet.create({
    icon : {
    color: iconColor,
    fontSize: iconSize
  }
}
```

Comment: Isso não responde à pergunta. Ele quer acessar a prop na declaração da stylesheet

Comment: Bem observado eu entendi errado o tópico, mas pelo o que vi você pode utilizar o styleSheet como uma função e passar as props  como parametro e utilizar na estilização 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707327/passing-props-into-external-stylesheet-in-react-native 

`export const styles = (iconColor,iconSize) => StyleSheet.create({
    icon : {
    color: iconColor,
    fontSize: iconSize
  }
}`

@RafaelTavares obrigada pela observação.